# Dynamic creation of sklearn pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, preprocessing, pipelines

I am trying to create an automatic pipeline builder functionality that takes into account a large set of conditions such as the existence of missing values, the scale of numerical features, etc., and automatically creates a scikit-learn pipeline instead of having to manually create them every time.

I'm aware of `pipeline.steps.append()` functionality that allows to assign new pipeline steps dynamically. However it seems to be not allowed to initialize an empty pipeline to start appending to; doing the following yields an error:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([])
```

This returns `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`.

Additionally, I also tried passing if conditions directly to pipeline steps the following way, again without success:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('numerical_scaler', StandardScaler(), num_columns_to_scale) if num_columns_to_scale,
    ('categorical_encoder', OneHotEncoder(), cat_columns_to_encode) if cat_columns_to_encode
])
```

This returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

What would be the best way to create such auto-pipelining functionality? As a dirty workaround I could obviously create a huge collection of if-else conditions to create pipelines that way but that is particularly error prone and difficult to maintain.

**Edit:** Point of this auto pipeline functionality is to speed up the creation of custom pipelines. Ideally I want to input a dataset, specify the target(s) and let the algorithm create a custom pipeline for the given dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This is still unclear what and why you wanted to do something like what you describe, if you add more context I will try to help.

You could solve the second point with `column_transformer`

```
from sklearn.pipeline import. Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer, make_column_selector as selector


numeric_transformer = Pipeline([("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy= "median")),
                                ("binning", KBinsDiscretizer(encode = "onehot-dense", strategy= "kmeans"))])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline([("Imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy= "constant", fill_value = "missing")),
                                ("encoding", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = "ignore"))])

preprocessor = make_column_transformer((numeric_transformer, selector(dtype_exclude = "object")), (categorical_transformer, selector(dtype_include = "object")))

pipeline = Pipeline([("proprocessing",preprocessor), ("model",LogisticRegression())])
```

Comment: I know about `make_column_selector` but this solution doesn't allow the same flexibility. I would like to have the option to specify the columns to apply OneHotEncoding on, not just blindly assume that all object-type features are to be one hot encoded. I added a bit of context to the post as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline's input is a list of steps, so you can dynamically create this list and then feed it into Pipeline object:

```
names        = ['numerical_scaler', 'categorical_encoder']
transformers = [StandardScaler(), OneHotEncoder()]
columns      = [num_columns_to_scale, cat_columns_to_encode]
steps = []
for name, transformer, cols in zip(names, transformers, columns):
    if len(cols) > 0:
        steps.append((name, transformer, cols))

pipe = Pipeline(steps)
```